# Как сделать прозрачную форму поиска

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать прозрачную форму поиска и такую кнопку возле неё?

```css
/*Search form*/
.search img{
    position: relative;
    top: 4px;
}

.search-form {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.search-form-input {
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 28px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 38px 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.search-form-btn {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
  top: 2px;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  line-height: 28px;

  /* Просто тюнинг внешнего вида */
  color: #666;
  font-weight: bold;      
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*and search form*/
```

```html
                        <form action="#" class="search-form">
                  <input type="search" class="search-form-input" placeholder="Subscribe our newsletter" />
                    <button type="submit" class="search-form-btn">
                       <img src="img/Search%201.png" alt="">
                    </button>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

поставьте `background: transparent;`
Если нужно, чтобы кнопка была за рамкой используйте border не на форме а на input

```css
body{
  background-color: blue;
}
/*Search form*/

.search img {
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
}

.search-form {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.search-form-input {

  max-width: 200px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 28px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 38px 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
  border-radius: 0;
  
  /*background-color: white;*/
  
  background: transparent;
  
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.search-form-btn {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
  top: 2px;
  width: 28px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 28px;
  /* Просто тюнинг внешнего вида */
  color: #666;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}


button img{
  width: 30px;
  height: 100%;
}

/*and search form*/
```

```html
<body>
<form action="#" class="search-form">
  <input type="search" class="search-form-input" placeholder="Subscribe our newsletter" />
  <button type="submit" class="search-form-btn">
                       <img src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/blue-arrow-png-22.png" alt="">
                    </button>
</form>
</body>
```

Вариант 2, почистил:

```css
body {
  background: url("https://3dnews.ru/assets/external/illustrations/2015/06/17/915789/kb4.jpg") 100% 100% no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  
  
}

* {
  box-sizing: padding-box;
}

.search-form-input {
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 35px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
  background: transparent;
  font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.search-form-btn {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .25);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>

    <form action="#" class="search-form">
      <input type="search" class="search-form-input" placeholder="Subscribe our newsletter" />
      <input type="image" class="search-form-btn" src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/blue-arrow-png-22.png" border="0" alt="Submit" />
    </form>

  </body>
```

Comment: а кнопка где????

Comment: Сейчас добавлю.

Comment: @Ruslan Semenov Вау спасибо, не подскажешь как вынести кнопку за блок формы поиска, как на скрине и что бы она работала?

Comment: Добавил вариант2, там немного проще и так как вам нужно, убрал лишнего, вообще можно еще почистить, но ваша задача выполнена. Заменил кнопку `button` на `input type="image"` которая сработает как submit

Comment: @Ruslan Semenov  Ага спасибо большое